# How can I disable Theme Info module in Drupal when it takes up too much memory to access the admin>>modules page?

Tags: drupal, themes

I'm TEN pages from finishing Using Drupal and I'm stuck. I turned on the Theme Info module to aid in theme customization. However, I can no longer access the admin>>modules page to turn on/off modules (including the Theme Info module). It brings up this white error page that says it tried to access about twice as much memory as is allowed. I could reinstall Drupal, but it'd be pretty lame if that's the only solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Landon

Comment: Looks like I don't need the answer to finish the book, but I'd still like to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options.

- Remove the 'Devel' module from your modules directory entirely. Reload the page. Voila! No Theme Info module. Downside: If you drag the module back in, it will still be enabled.
- Open PHPMyAdmin (if you're using MAMP, WAMP, or a server that has it installed) and run the following query: UPDATE system SET status = 0 WHERE name = 'devel_themer';

Those should work to disable any module "in a pinch." You can also edit the php.ini file in your MAMP/WAMP configuration to give it more memory temporarily, though that trick won't work if you're running on a shared host that doesn't recognize php.ini changes.

Answer (score 0):

First apply Eaton's suggestion (I prefer the second one).

Then increase `memory_limit` in your php.ini config (usually `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`). A WSOD for just that module means you really don't have enough RAM per script for anything serious: most configurations these days needs 32M at least.